# black screen after install Nvidia drive 304.125 on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: nvidia

After install Nvidia drive 304.125 on ubuntu 15.04 display black screen i tried nomodeset but still the problem

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me as well, i am sure there is a way to make it work but i recommend you to boot a live cd, save everything you need and re install ubuntu 15.04.

Visit this link to learn how to upgrade your other drivers :)

[How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)